# Flask-Bootstrap combining flash message in one block

Tags: flask

I'm using flask-bootstrap in my project, and the only quirk left is that each flash message gets displayed in their own block, so they "pile-up" pretty fast when a page display 3 messages.  And always in the orange color, no matter what category I gave them.  Is there a way to override that behavior and combine flash message in a single block that use the right color of the category?

Comment: Post the code you're using to display flashed messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code I use to display flash messages, I am using twitter `bootstrap` `html/css/js` files which I manually added. To enable the categories you need the second line in the code. I have the `{% if category == 'message' %}` because the default flash category is called `'message'` and I want to display that as a warning. You also have to make sure that your category names match the `css` `classes`. The `classes` are 'success', 'info', 'warning' and 'danger' in the basic [bootstrap theme](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/).

```
<div>
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
            {% if category == 'message' %}
              <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            {% else %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert">
            {% endif %}
              {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
</div>
```

To get them all to appear within one block you simply have to move the for-loop in the template within the div.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ messages.0.0 }}" role="alert">
      {% for category, message in messages %}
        {{ message }} </br>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Where `message.0.0` is to get the category of the first message. You can also look at the last example in the [flash examples](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/) to see how to group together different message categories.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make this work with flask-bootstrap flashed_messages macro :)