# Using flask flash pushes down all the contents

Tags: python, flask, response

I m working on a project.I am using Flask.Flask flash is gives a message but pushes all the contents down.Can anyone suggest a better method to give responsive messages similar to session.flash in web2py

Comment: I'd say use JavaScript...however, what's your problem? What do you mean about *pushes down all the contents* ? Can you give us a [mcve] about your problem? Thanks!

Comment: I mean the flash message should pop-over the page than on the page @KevinGuan

Comment: Well, that's what `flash` does. If you just want the message pop-over the page, really, learn JavaScript maybe is a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes to your css. Somewhere in your css, you must have a `.flashes` class, change its properties.
If class `flashes` is not present in css, define it
and then add `position:absolute` to it.

Comment: Is there any built in modules like Flask-flash

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a about any other built in modules that might help you. But have a look at this [flash-design-patterns](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/) and [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106114/flask-bootstrap-combining-flash-message-in-one-block)

Also please accept the answer if it helped you. :)